# Proving antipode of Hopf algebra property

Tags: hopf-algebras

So I am trying to show $\epsilon(S(a)) = \epsilon(a)$, where $\epsilon$ is the co-unit and $S$ is the antipode.
\begin{align}
  \epsilon(S(a))
  &= \epsilon( S( \sum_{(a)} a^{(1)} \epsilon(a^{(2)}) ) )  \\
  &= \epsilon( S( \sum_{(a)} \epsilon(a^{(1)}) a^{(2)} ) )  \\
  &= \epsilon( \sum_{(a)} \epsilon(a^{(1)}) S(a^{(2)}) )    \\
  &= \epsilon( \epsilon(a) I )                              \\
  &= \epsilon(a)
\end{align}
However, I am unsure of the last 3 lines. Particularly the case
$$
  \sum_{(a)} \epsilon(a^{(1)}) S(a^{(2)}) = \epsilon(a)I
$$
What is the identity that is used here?

Comment: What does the notation $a^{(1)}$ mean?

Comment: @KentaS it is Sweedler notation for the coproduct.

Comment: I am not sure even whether the claim is true or not, but the last equation means $S = \eta \epsilon$ where $\eta$ is the unit $1$. This is not true in general case.

Comment: I found the proof in a textbook. @MathDrifter

Answer (score 1):

The identity in question
$$
  \sum_{(a)} ε( a^{(1)} ) S( a^{(2)} )
  =
  ε(a) 1_H
  \tag{$\ast$}
$$
isn’t true.
To see this, we consider for a non-trivial group $G$ and its group-algebra $[G]$.
The comultiplication, counit and antipode of $[G]$ are given by
$$
  Δ(g) = g ⊗ g \,,
  \quad
  ε(g) = 1 \,,
  \quad
  S(g) = g^{-1}
$$
for every element $g$ of $G$.
It follows that for every non-trivial element $g$ of $G$,
$$
  \sum_{(g)} ε( g^{(1)} ) S( g^{(2)} )
  =
  ε( g ) S( g )
  =
  1 ⋅ g^{-1}
  =
  g^{-1}
  ≠
  1
  =
  ε(g) \,.
$$

---

If we take a step back, then we see that the identity $(\ast)$ can’t make sense.
We arived at the left-hand side of $(\ast)$ from the chain of (correct) equalities
$$
  S(a)
  =
  S\biggl( \sum_{(a)} ε( a^{(1)} ) a^{(2)} \biggr)
  =
  \sum_{(a)} ε( a^{(1)} ) S( a^{(2)} ) \,.
$$
Therefore, the formula $(\ast)$ is just a complicated reformulation of the equivalent formula
$$
  S(a) = ε(a) 1_H \,.
$$
And this is clearly nonsense.